# jQuery fake a window resize

Tags: jquery, resize

I found a script on StackOverflow that does a pretty good job on scaling text to fit a container [How to scale text size compared to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745489/how-to-scale-text-size-compared-to-container/21745965#21745965). After trying plugins like FitText and textFill and not really doing the job for me.

Anyway, this script works pretty well but it's having a small problem working with google fonts. In normal fonts it works fine, but when I use a google font I need to resize my window for the script to work.

My JS skills are too low to fix this, so I was wondering if there's a way to fake a window resize. I tried putting

```
$(window).resize
```

at the end of my jquery file but it doesn't seem to do much.

Answer (score 7):

make a function call

```
$(window).resize()
```

you could also try native js

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

update:

you should put this :

```
var fontMetrics = document.getElementById('font-metrics');
var scaleTexts  = $('.scale-text');
updateFontSize();
```

into your document ready function before the resize trigger, maybe you dont even need to trigger the resize at all then

Comment: yep, or use trigger `$(window).trigger("resize")`

Comment: Thanks for the input but it's not working (the way I think it should). I put my site online for you to see if you want, http://no-illusions.nl/cleanpixel/ 

I put the 

    `$(window).trigger('resize'); `

in my JS file and it should execute it after the resizing script but no luck.

Comment: @Peter for some things the resize has to be called twice. like `ko-grid` and `ng-grid` if they were rendered hidden before being made visible. Also it could be your timing.. are you waiting for page load or dom ready or anything like that?

Comment: @johnSmith It allready has that, and duplicating it doesn't seem to help. Maybe I should try another way of importing the font.