# CSS & AngularJS: how to set elements' content (e.g. text) size according to container size?

Tags: css, angularjs

I found this answer: [How to scale text size compared to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745489/how-to-scale-text-size-compared-to-container)
but it actually makes use of Javascript and looks like a wordaround. I also found this library: http://fittextjs.com/ .

I have a container like this:

```
<div id="top-bar">
    <div id="element-1" class="element-contained">{{text1}}</div>
    <div id="element-2" class="element-contained">{{text2}}</div>
    <div id="element-3" class="element-contained">{{text3}}</div>
</div>

#top-bar{
   height: 50px;
   width: 100%;
}

.element_contained{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Given that {{text1/2/3}} is variable (according to the language chosen by the user, the screen resolution and the actual text which is updated over time), how do I adjust dynamically **width** and **height** (possibly JS-free) of these texts in a way that it doesn't word-wrap or get cut?

Comment: there is not a javascript free way of adjusting font size dynamically, even with css3. Which is why libraries like fittextjs exist. And unless your text is in an image format, changing the width and height will not change the size of the font, you'd need to change the `font-size` attribute.

Comment: Also why did you tag this as angularjs? angularjs is a javascript framework, so why wouldn't you want to use javascript?

Comment: you are right. I just tried avoid using Jquery in my angularjs app. But if it's the only solution, I'll take it :)